# How to make a python script executable?

Tags: python, windows, user-interface

I have a files monitor project in python and i want to get benefit from this prject by selling it.
My first question is how can I design a simple interface for the user just to do simple things? and can I use css or it's not possible?
How can I turn the .py file into .exe to share it with my clients securely?
At last, if anyone has some ideas that can help me to sell my project I will be grateful if you share your knowledge with me.

Honestly I searched a lot on youtube but did't find the answer to my questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually convert your Python file (.py) into executable (.exe) using [pyinstaller](https://realpython.com/pyinstaller-python/) as well as other tools, also, for the UI, if you're willing to create a GUI using style sheets, PySide or PyQt might be a good choice. as they let you style UIs with something called QSS (kinda like CSS).
and if you want to use something more in web (CSS/JS/HTML), you can just use [Eel](https://pypi.org/project/Eel/).